# Kubernetes tls host different from ingress host

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, tls1.2, kubernetes-secrets

Currently working on some ingress in kubernetes cluster, in ingress there are 2 hosts. I am wondering why is tls-host different from rules:host?

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test1.something.se
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 5000
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test2.something.se
    secretName: tls-secret
```

Answer (score 1):

That indicates that the host `test2.something.se` has https traffic enabled, and the certificate is stored in the `tls-secret` secret

Since I don't see a rule specifying that host, or a fallback default rule, traffic for test2 will 404.

Traffic for `test1.something.se` will not be https enabled because its hostname isn't under the `tls.hosts` list